# Angular5: Null check while buidling full name

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular5, ecmascript-5

I am trying to build fullName from first, last and middle initial

staff.fullName = `${staff.lastName}, ${staff.firstName} ${staff.middleInitial}.`

I tried building the staff like above. But I don't want to show , if firstname doesn't exist and doesn't want to show . if middleInitial doesn't exist. I am trying to see if there is an easy way to do null check here

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
{staff.lastName == null ? '' : staff.lastName}
```

If it's null it will return ''

Answer (score 0):

Only set when the both the props exist.

```
if ( staff.firstName && staff.middleInitial) {
    staff.fullName = `${staff.lastName}, ${staff.firstName} ${staff.middleInitial}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try by commenting `firstName` and `middleInitial` one by one in the `staff` Object:

```js
let staff = {
  lastName: 'Doe',
  firstName: 'John',
  middleInitial: 'H'
};

let name = `${staff.lastName} ${staff.firstName ? ', ' + staff.firstName : ''} ${staff.middleInitial ? staff.middleInitial + '.' : ''}`;
console.log(name);
```